# Problemas com for in

Tags: python

```
propaganda_online= [
     {
     'tempo_gasto_site': 68.95, 'idade':30, 'pais': 'Brasil'},
     {
     'tempo_gasto_site': 80.23, 'idade': 45,'pais': 'Japao'},
     {
     'tempo_gasto_site': 69.47, 'idade': 18,'pais':'Canada',},
     {
     'tempo_gasto_site': 80.23, 'idade': 51,'pais': 'Russia'},
```

Quero imprimir somente os países que tem idade maior que 30 anos

`i=0` esse aqui é meu contador.

```
for a in propaganda_online: 
 
  if (propaganda_online[i]['idade']) >=30:

    print(propaganda_online[i]['idade'])
    i+=1
    

else:
   print('proximo citado n tem')
```

Ele imprime ate a segunda linha, a terceira ele cai no else e ocorre ali, como que faço para ele continuar ou pular???

Comment: Você chama uma variável `i` inexistente dentro do seu `for in`, deveria ser `propaganda_online[a]` ao invés de `propaganda_online[i]`.

Comment: opa,mals colei errado ali ,o meu 'i' eu coloquei antes do for in,ele ta forado laço i=0....dps vem o for a

Comment: agr q to vendo q ta poluida a tela

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: i=0;;;;;;;
for a in propaganda_online:;;;; 
 
  if (propaganda_online[i]['idade']) >=30:;;;;;

    print(propaganda_online[i]['cidade'],propaganda_online[i]['idade']);;;;;;;;
    i+=1;;;;
    
else:;;;;;
   print('o proxima n tem');;;;;

Comment: espero q de p entender,,entao,, em resumo, meu contador para com 2 ,ai ele ja ta dentro do else , preciso q ele continue para o 3 para a continuaçao, EX: 0(if). 1(if). 2(else) .3(if)

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta e acrescentar um [mcve]. Pelo pouco que deu para entender da pergunta você está tentando fazer isso? https://ideone.com/rMLqbJ

Comment: caraca , como ,é isso msm q estou  tendo fazer, tentando fazer a dias, como chego nisso não sei,mas agr vou pesquiasr melhor sob esse map e filter,na moral tu me salvou,mt obrigado!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você não precisa de um contador para esse caso, a variável `a` no seu `for loop` é sempre atualizada com o próximo objeto no seu iterável, ou seja, inicia com o elemento 0 de sua lista, na próxima iteração recebe o elemento na posição 1, e assim sucessivamente. Dessa forma, você pode realizar o condicional direto na variável `a` (para deixar o código mais legível, substitui o `a` por `propaganda`):

```python
for propaganda in propaganda_online:
    if propaganda['idade']>30:
        print(propaganda['pais'])
```

Comment: eu coloquei o contador pq esta dado varias repetiçoes da msm cidade,,mas teu codigo   é a resposta q eu procurava, vlw irmao, quebrou um galho

Comment: Que bom que ajudei! Se possível, aceite minha resposta como solução do problema, clicando no símbolo de "visto".